# SPRING 3 MVC - URI template error?

Tags: spring-mvc

Here is the code for my controller class:

```
package edu.byu.cio.test.web.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */


@Controller
 public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/")

 public String helloWorld() {

 System.out.println("HomeController: Passing through...");

 return "WEB-INF/views/home.jsp";
 }


@RequestMapping(value="/name/{Name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

 public String compare(@PathVariable("Name") String Name) {

 return "WEB-INF/views/home.jsp";

 }


}
```

I am interested in calling the second method.

When i do the get request as:

```
http://localhost:8081/mvc-basic/name/somename
```

**Note**:I have configured it to listen at port 8081.

I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /mvc-basic/name/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /mvc-basic/name/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp

description The requested resource (/mvc-basic/name/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp) is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
```

I think the URI pattern is right yet I am wondering why is it showing this error. Do you find any errors in the above code? I appreciate your help.

Comment: now format the code, give us your dispatcher-servlet configuration, and remove the multiple question marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem when I first worked on Spring Source Tool suite. After so much of struggle i figured out it to be problem with the controller class is not latest.

When i first wrote similar piece of code i did not use URI template variable and deployed it on the tc server. later I added URI template and re published/ restarted server many times thinking the controller class would have been built automatically.

Later I found that I am running the project with 'Build Automatically' unchecked on 'project' menu.

please make sure you check 'Build Automatically' if you use STS or any eclipse based tools and make sure u deploy latest Controller class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your viewResolver bean from your *-servlet.xml context file to be sure, but chances are your view resolver has a ".jsp" suffix defined, which means you don't need to specify it. The root directory for your JSPs will also be defaulting to /WEB-INF.

Instead of returning "WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" in your controller, try returning "views/home".